# Openlayers - arrary of info into popupmarker

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a connection to a database(db). I am getting the lon, lat and name from the db and stroing them:

```
while ($row_ChartRS = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
{
$latitude=$row_ChartRS['latitude'];
$longitude=$row_ChartRS['longitude'];
$bus_name =$row_ChartRS['short_name'];
//echo  $latitude.'--'.$longitude.'<br>';
echo  $bus_name;
```

I then create a map to display the data. The markers are working fine for all lat, lon locations. Code:

```
function init()
  {

    projLonLat   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // WGS 1984
    projMercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // Spherical Mercator

    overviewMap = new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap();

    //adding scale ruler
    scale = new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine();
    scale.geodesic = true; // get the scale projection right, at least on small

    map = new OpenLayers.Map('demoMap',
                             { controls: [ new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),    // direct panning via mouse drag
                                           new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),   // attribution text
                                           new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),    // where am i?
                                           new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),    // switch between layers
                                           new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),    // larger navigation control
                                           scale,
                                           overviewMap                             // overview map
                                         ]
                             }
                            );

    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Mapnik("Mapnik"));
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM.Osmarender("Osmarender"));


    //Create an explicit OverviewMap object and maximize its size after adding it to the map so that it shows
    //as activated by default.
    overviewMap.maximizeControl();

    //Adding a marker
    markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Vehicles");
    map.addLayer(markers);

    vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Routes');
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

    for (k in Locations)
    {

    //adding a popup for the marker
    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature(markers, new OpenLayers.LonLat(Locations[k].lon, Locations[k].lat).transform(projLonLat,projMercator));

    //true to close the box
    feature.closeBox = true;

    feature.popupClass = new OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Popup.AnchoredBubble,
    {
      //create the size of the box
      'autoSize': true,
      'maxSize': new OpenLayers.Size(100,100)
    });

    //add info into box
    for (z in names)
    {
    feature.data.popup = new OpenLayers.Feature(new OpenLayers.LonLat(names[z]).transform(projLonLat,projMercator));

    }

    //puts a scroll button on box to scroll down to txt
    //feature.data.overflow = "auto";

    marker = feature.createMarker();
    marker.display(true);

    markerClick = function (evt) {
      if (this.popup == null) {
        this.popup = this.createPopup(this.closeBox);
        map.addPopup(this.popup);
        this.popup.show();
      } else {
        this.popup.toggle();
      }
      currentPopup = this.popup;
      OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
    };

    marker.events.register("mousedown", feature, markerClick);
    markers.addMarker(marker);
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(Locations[k].lon, Locations[k].lat).transform(projLonLat,projMercator), zoom);

    var lonLat1 = new OpenLayers.LonLat(Locations[k].lon,Locations[k].lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'), map.getProjectionObject());
    var pos2=new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonLat1.lon,lonLat1.lat);
    points1.push(pos2);


    //Uncomment to put boxes in when map opens
    //feature.popup = feature.createPopup(feature.closeBox);
    //map.addPopup(feature.popup);
    //feature.popup.show()
      }

  var lineString = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points1);
  var lineFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(lineString,'',style_green);
  vectorLayer.addFeatures([lineFeature]);
  map.setCenter(lonLat1,zoom);

  } //function
```

However the name in the popup marker is the same for all markers. i.e. the last name pulled from the db. Can anyone please help with this - I have spent 3 full days trying to fix it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:

1. The PHP code you’ve posted is completely irrelevant, since it’s not seen to be used anywhere.
2. The objects `names` and `Locations` aren’t declared anywhere in the code you posted. What do they contain?
3. In the code quoted below, you’re creating multiple new `Feature` objects, but you assign them all to the same property (thereby overwriting that property each time).  Is that intentional?

   ```
   //add info into box
   for (z in names) {
       feature.data.popup = new OpenLayers.Feature(new OpenLayers.LonLat(names[z]).transform(projLonLat,projMercator));
   }
   ```

**Edit:**
This does appear to be where it’s going wrong.  You should remove the for...z loop, and replace it with the following code:

```
//add info into box
feature.data.popup = new OpenLayers.Feature(new OpenLayers.LonLat(names[k]).transform(projLonLat,projMercator));
```

Since in PHP, you’re using the same index (`$v`) to fill both arrays, it makes sense to use the same index to read them in javascript...

---

Aside from that, using the `for...in` loop on Javascript arrays is not considered good practice, for [a number of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays).  It’s better to use the following:

```
for (k = 0; k < Locations.length; k += 1) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: @ Martijn thank you for your response. Please see the above code to see how they are used.

Comment: @user639439: Thanks for the PHP code. I’ve updated my answer; if you change your code as suggested, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem , and i solve it ...
the problem is overwrite
you don't have to loop inside your function , do the loop for function for example:

```
function init(z)
{
    feature.data.popup = new OpenLayers.Feature(new OpenLayers.LonLat(names[z]).transform(projLonLat,projMercator));
}


for (z in names)
{
    init(z)
}
```